# SQL Server managed backup missing in ssms

Tags: sql-server, backup, ssms, azure

Trying to configure Sql Managed backup to azure, and it seems that "Managed backup" is missing from the GUI under Management in SSMS 17.2

All guides I see kind of implies that it's already there. But if its missing, then what is needed to make it show in the Gui? An Azure backup client installation? A command?

Now it seems that you need to run a command to enable the managed backup on the instance, but if that fails, you can't use the gui, because it doesn't show.

Tried SQL Server 2016 Standard and 2016 datacenter evaluation. Using latest SSMS 17.2.

Comment: In which version of ssms you see this working?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was added in 2014, but then removed in SQL Server 2016 ... that is what i have personally discovered; but i have not found an authoritive document anywhere saying it was done, all i can find is the CMD line options to enable it.